# Why AlarmManager executes Async Http Request twice?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-async-http

UPDATE:
I've found my "twice" problem reason. I started "runAlarm()" twice.
So the code below  works okay.
It sends  Async HTTP request periodically. 
You should add to manifest this line:

```
<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="Alarm"></receiver>
```

ORIGINAL QUESTION:
I did HTTP  requests periodically using AlarmManager.
It works okay in loop.
But each HTTP request is executed twice.
I've used some AlarmManager example without understanding what means "bla-bla" there.
If you ask me why I don't use Timer,
my answer is that I get error trying to touch Views out of timer thread to show results of HTTP requests.
My code is below.
Thanks in advance!.

```
    private void startHttpRequests() {
         setAlarm();
    }

public void setAlarm()
{
    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override public void onReceive( Context context, Intent _ )
        {
            asyncPostRequest();
            context.unregisterReceiver( this ); // this == BroadcastReceiver, not Activity
        }
    };
    this.registerReceiver( receiver, new IntentFilter("com.blah.blah.somemessage") );
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent("com.blah.blah.somemessage"), 0 );
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));
    pollPeriod=1000*10;
    manager.set( AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + pollPeriod, pintent );
}
private void asyncPostRequest() {
    new HttpPostDemo().execute("http://www.google.com");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result)  //HTTP POST result
{
    printDebug("received="+result);
    setAlarm();
}

public class HttpPostDemo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        BufferedReader inBuffer = null;
        String url= urls[0];
        String result = "fail";
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
            List<NameValuePair> postParameters =
                    new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("operanda", "5"));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("operandb", "6"));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("answer", "11"));
            UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                    postParameters);

            request.setEntity(formEntity);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
            inBuffer = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = inBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(line + newLine);
            }
            inBuffer.close();

            result = stringBuffer.toString();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            // Do something about exceptions
            result = e.getMessage();
        } finally {
            if (inBuffer != null) {
                try {
                    inBuffer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: If you want your alarm to execute periodically, It would be better to use manager.setInexactRepeating instead of setting the alarm repeatedly. Don't even have to register and unregister BoradcastReceiver again and again.

Comment: okay, thanks. I will google how to do it.

Comment: No, not understood concering setInexactRepeating. It is possible to just skip every second HTTP request in my code. I wonder that it is a big headache to send HTTP requests periodically...

Comment: I am not sure about second http request but even if you resolve that issue, I think you should change your implementation even then, as it is not the good way to implement repeating alarm. Give a try to my answer given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class HttpRequestAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0;

    private static final String TAG_CLASS_NAME = HttpRequestAlarm.class
            .getName();

    private Context context;

    private int timeInterval;

    public HttpRequestAlarm() {
    }

    public HttpRequestAlarm(Context context, int timeInterval) {
        this.context = context;
        this.timeInterval = timeInterval;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        asyncPostRequest();
    }

    public void start() {
        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(context, HttpRequestAlarm.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                REQUEST_CODE, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis(), timeInterval * 1000, pendingIntent);
        Log.i(TAG_CLASS_NAME, "Alarm scheduled for every " + timeInterval
                + " seconds");
    }

    public void stop() {
        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(context, HttpRequestAlarm.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                REQUEST_CODE, intentAlarm, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        Log.i(TAG_CLASS_NAME, "Alarm stopped");
    }
}
```

**Register receiver only once in your project's Manifest.xml as below**

```
    <receiver android:name="<your.package.name.>HttpRequestAlarm" />
```

And finally create an object of HttpRequestAlarm and call start method. This will schedule your alarm to trigger repeatedly after every provided timeInterval.

**Note:** If you want to execute your http call even when your device is alseep then you will have to acquire wakelock before http call and release it once call completes.

Comment: I got null pointer exception starting it here: private void startAlarm() {
        HttpRequestAlarm httpRequestAlarm=new HttpRequestAlarm();
        httpRequestAlarm.start();
    }. Thanks!

Comment: Editing the manifest after "." press after '<receiver android:name="<my.package.name'  I don't see "HttpRequestAlarm" hint in my IntelliJ. But no compilation errors.

Comment: Oops. Pardon.I started it as  httpRequestAlarm.start(this, 10). But no alarms. No requests. Thanks

Comment: is there any change you are putting your device to sleep mode? I think it should work properly. Can you cross verify once again if you have done everything right. Use (http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/android-alarmmanager-tutorial.html) tutorial to cross verify.

Comment: Unfortunately your code does not work. No. There are no any changes to put device to sleep mode. Thank you for tutorial reference. But I found my "twice" problem. I started  setAlarm() twice. Now it is all okay. No promlems after a few hours working. I can stop alarm if I don't execute  setAlarm() again. So it seems my code is correct. Does it make sense to change it? But I don't know: will it send alarms in sleep mode. But I don't need it. My line is manifest is as follows:<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="Alarm"></receiver>. Thanks for help!

Comment: It doesn't need any explicit code to put device into sleep mode. As soon as you switch off your screen it goes to sleep mode within few seconds to save battery. As I already said yours is not the correct way to implement repeating timer and I would suggest to put some more efforts and get it working the other way. Still if you are ok with it then its  fine. :)

Comment: Prashant Kedia, I tried again your code. No. It does not work. I tried a few different examples. And they also do not work for unknown reason... But thank you anyway!